# Whatever happens, it is 0

Tags: c++, recursion

```
unsigned long long F(unsigned long long p, unsigned long long N)
{
    unsigned long long s = 0ull;

    if (p < N)
        for (int i = p+1; (N-i) > i; ++i)
            s += F(i, N-i);

    return s;
}
```

function always returning zero, despite to what on input. Why is it happening?

Comment: Because you set `s` to `0` each time the function is called.

Comment: (N-i) > i, seriously?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about providing a certain input and expecting a different result.

Comment: @juanchopanza So, he then adds the result of the other calls of `F` to it.

Comment: @RedX: And how can any of those calls return anything other than zero?

Comment: Did you ever try to use a debugger to see whats happen?

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right, there is never any other value assigned to it. Sorry.

Comment: Side note: don't you agree that `i < N/2` is more readable than `(N-i) > i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the recursion not to be infinite the `if` or the `for` bodies must not be executed in the deeper nested call. That function will be equivalent to `unsigned long long s = 0ull; return s;` and return 0. The caller will add that 0 to it's local variable `s` yielding 0. All of the calls to `F` end up adding 0s and returning the result.

Comment: Good answer. Almost the only response not simply berating.

Answer (score 4):

What is `F()` supposed to do?

It really returns zero for every `p, N` - you have to add some nonzero value to `s` somewhere, you only add to `s` result of `F(...)`, which is, again, zero.

Haven't you miss some other value that you wanted to add to `s` at some line?

Answer (score 2):

Take the following function, which is a simplified version of yours:

```
int F(int a, int b)
{
    int c = 0;

    if (a < b)
    {
        c += F(a + 1, b);
    }

    return c;
}
```

The call `F(1, 3)` goes as follows:

```
F(1, 3)
c = 0 +
    F(2, 3)
    c = 0 +
        F(3, 3)
        c = 0

0 + 0 + 0 = 0
```

As others have already mentioned, because you are initializing `c = 0`, you are getting a result of zero.

Comment: Comment as on David's answer